# Makefile: missing separator

Tags: makefile

This is my Makefile:

```
obj-m +=hello.o

all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
rm -rf *.o *.mod.o *.order  
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I am getting a "missing separator" error at the `rm -rf` statement. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this formatted correctly? Makefiles require that the commands for a dependency be tabbed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "missing separator" error is caused by a missing tab "\t" in front of `rm -rf ...`, i.e., it should be

```
clean:
<tab-here>rm -rf ...
```

This is needed for any entry to a target (also in front of your `make ...` lines).